# Is "fulfilment" pluralized to "fulfilments"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Where I work, we use the term "fulfilment" to mean the way the product is delivered to the end user. But a co-worker and I are having a disagreement on whether "fulfilment" needs an to have an "s" suffix when referring to multiple fulfilments/fulfilment.

I believe "fulfilment" is singular, but my co-worker thinks the word is a mass noun. I can't find any information online about the plurality of fulfilment.

Comment: Are you thinking of "singular nouns" and "mass nouns" as mutually exclusive categories? What do you mean exactly by "singular"; do you interpret this description as only applying to count nouns? There are many mass nouns that take singular verb agreement, such as "water," "ice", "sand" and so on.

Comment: ***fulfilment*** is an [abstract noun](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-abstract-nouns.html). As per other examples listed on that link *(Courage, Curiosity, Dedication, Determination, Ego, Elegance, Enthusiasm, Envy, Evil, Generosity, etc.)*, you wouldn't normally think of abstract nouns as "plural" in most contexts. And you certainly wouldn't say anything like *The firefighters' **courages** were exceptional.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, we use the term "fulfilment" to mean the way the product is delivered to the end user.

Comment: Yes, "fulfilment" is a non-count singular noun. It normally has an abstract interpretation.

Comment: You should edit your question to provide *a specific context* where you want to use the word, and explain why you think it might be desirable or necessary to convey "plurality" in that context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers done!

Comment: Well, in the context of your exact text *when referring to multiple fulfilments/fulfilment* it's effectively impossible to avoid pluralising the term. But frankly, it's such an oddball usage that I suspect most people would be tempted to put "scare quotes" around the word anyway (or just go with the majority and use a more natural word for the context, such as ***completion***).

Comment: @RobAiken There is no plural "fulfilments" in normal usage in Standard English. And even if there was, it would not be a count noun.

Comment: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fulfilment) licenses the count- and plural-form usage: << _fulfillment_ [COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE] the act of something happening or being made to happen
fulfilment of: the fulfilment of a prediction/prophecy >> I'm not unhappy with "There have been multiple fulfillments of this prophecy: at least six."

Comment: The Macmillan source seems to be an "open" dictionary.  Six "fulfillments" of a prophecy sounds sarcastic to me.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.  If you give us the context and sentence where the issue arises, we can help you and your colleague sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

Wordsmith has it right here, the other replies are missing the point (and a tad snide).  Your usage (meaning something like "completed order") is part of your workplace jargon.  Because this is jargon, you will not find an official right answer to your question.  Perhaps someday, if your usage spreads - especially to the general public -  a custom for pluralizing it will emerge. Your co-worker is following his ear and the standard usage of the term, but since you are using the term in such a non-standard way, adding the "s" seems like just part of the jargon territory. Given the way you have concretized and singularized this mass noun it sounds far more peculiar to then *not* add an "s" when pluralizing.  Consider,"Can you forward me the paperwork for the five fulfillment you did yesterday".  It is hard to even write this let alone say it, and "five fulfillment" sounds like the rank one might achieve in some cult.  I recommend either abandoning the jargon, or embrace it and use the plural "s".

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fulfilment) considers "fulfillment" to be a mass noun. With that being said, this is what *Garner's Modern English Usage* has to say about mass nouns and plurals:

> "A recent trend in the language is to make plurals for mass nouns—i.e., general and abstract nouns that cannot be broken down into discrete units and that therefore should not have plural forms. One example of this phenomenon is the psychologists' and sociologists' term *behaviors* (= actions), suggesting that the ways in which people behave are readily categorizable and therefore countable. Granted, one can have good or bad behavior, but not, traditionally speaking, *a* good behavior or *a* bad behavior. This is jargon.
>
> Increasingly, though, speakers of English think of *technologies* and *methodologies* as being discrete things. And to weather forecasters, it makes perfect sense to speak of *humidities* and *accumulations*. In part, this trend seems to show two things: first, an affection for abstract terms; and second, a resulting tendency to reify those abstract terms."

And this is what he says about mass nouns and count nouns in general:

> "Count nouns are those that denote enumerable things and that are capable of forming plurals (e.g., *cranes, parties, minivans, oxen*); mass (noncount) nouns are often abstract nouns—they cannot be enumerated (e.g., *insurance, courage, mud*). Many nouns can be both count {he gave several talks} and mass {talk is cheap}, depending on the sense. These are few, however, in comparison to the nouns that are exclusively either count or mass. Use of these two types of nouns may introduce problems with number, especially when the use of count nouns strays into a use of mass nouns or vice versa.

Additionally, "jargon" is basically defined as such: "Jargon refers to the special, usually technical, idiom of any social, occupational, or professional group. It arises to streamline communication,  to save time and space—and occasionally to conceal meaning from the uninitiated." This was also taken from *GMEU*, but it is far too long for me to write out the full passage. If you want, you can take a look at page 535 in the fourth edition of *Garner's Modern English Usage*.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.google.com/), [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/), and plenty of other websites regard fulfilments as the plural, although it is also grammatically correct to use fulfilment. I recommend using fulfilment for your writing because it is easier to understand as a reader.
Since these links might be dead soon I have the definition below:

Noun

fulfilment (countable and uncountable, *plural fulfilments*)**

1. The act of fulfilling.
2. The state or quality of being fulfilled; completion; realization.
3. The act of consummating a desire or promise.
4. (business) The activities performed once an order is received to fulfill the order; packaging, distributing and shipping goods.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer.  Often links can become dead or change over time.  It would be a good idea to take the definition given on one (or both) of the links and post here as well.